# Is there a way to localize error messages from bison/flex?

Tags: localization, bison, flex-lexer

Do bison and flex allow user to natively localize error messages?
For example, I would like to translate following message: *syntax error, unexpected NUMBER, expecting $end* to other language and replace NUMBER/$end with something more human-readable.

Comment: @Carl, thanks for the suggestion. When I tried to accept answers few days ago I wasn't able because I got message that I need more reputation points to do that. (but now, fortunately I was able to accept answers)

Answer (score 1):

Use yyerror and YY_USER_ACTION for additional data.

```
void yyerror(const char *s) {
    sprintf(dummmy, "%s line %d col %d word '%s'\n", s, myline, mycolumn, yytext);
    print_error(dummmy);
```

in the lex file

```
#define YY_USER_ACTION \
    addme(yy_start, yytext); \
    mycolumn += yyleng;\
    if(*yytext == '\n') { myline++; mycolumn = 0; } else 0; \
```